# Apple App ID need to change name

Tags: ios, iphone

Do I have to create a new ID if the App name changed?  I'm concerned that the name on the App Store will be wrong if I don't change the App ID name.  I changed the Product Name on the app it self.

Comment: Just a note: If your app's original name is "My App" (*showing under the icon when installed*) and (*for SEO like purpose*) you want to change it in only in AppStore while submitting new release/binary like "My Awesome App" it is ok, if it doesn't change the whole meaning of the previous app's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the App ID I assume you mean the bundle ID, this needs to stay the same during your entire apps release as it ties your app to the app store, the user does not see this as they will only see the product and App name so theres no need to change it

Comment: Great, thanks, it was kind of confusing because the App ID has the bundle and a name below it on the web site.